# Edit armature without changing pose(s)

Tags: rigging

I've started posing a rigged character, and realized during that the roll values on some of the bones weren't properly mirrored. This causes the "mirror X" option to not work: a closed fist on one hand leads to fingers twisted in all directions on the other.

Is it possible to change to roll values while keeping the pose as-is, so as not to lose any work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make changes to the rig and have no repercussions on the already made animation data.

But you can use the Copy Global Transform addon:

[image: copy addon]

This allows you to copy and paste poses in world space. So what you can do is:

1. Copy your pose
2. Change the roll
3. paste your pose

The result will be the same as before the roll change. Though, it's annoying to do on multiple poses. There might be ways to automate this using python.